# Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de carregar um jquery antes da pagina ser carregada

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

-estou testando para carregar o resto apenas coloquei um id no body para ver se iria

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#body").load(function(){

          var tip = $(this).find("#sessaocad").val();

         if (tip == "Banco"){
           $("#tipousu").css("display","none"); 
            $("#tipousulbl").css("display","none");

           $("#tiposang").css("display","none");
           $("#tiposanglbl").css("display","none");

           $("#rg").css("display","none");  

           $("#cnpj").css("display","block");  
       } 
       if (tip == "Pessoa"){
         //MOSTRA 
           $("#tipousu").css("display","block"); 
           $("#tipousulbl").css("display","block");

           $("#tiposang").css("display","block");
           $("#tiposanglbl").css("display","block");

           $("#rg").css("display","block");  

           $("#cnpj").css("display","none");  
       }
       });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: O que você obteve como resultado?

Comment: nada, a pagina carrega mas dependo do meu tipo de login ela teria que ser alterada  porem eu acho que como a função só é chamada apos a  pagina carregar nenhum alteração é feita, por isso gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira desse jquery ser executado antes da pagina ser carregada

Answer (score 0):

A função ready() como pode verificar na [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) em outras palavras ela somente executa o que tem dentro dela após o carregamento do seu seletor está seguro "completamente carregado" como você está usando o $(document) como seletor ele só vai executar após carregar tudo.

uma possível solução seria criar sua regra fora do

... $(document).ready(function() { ...

uma dica pra organizar seu código use arquivos .js (externos)  ao invés de escrever seus códigos dentro da pagina.